# Timestamp(Time difference) with respect to current Time

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

I am using below piece of code to get the current date and time
Whereas the time is displayed wrongly here, it shows less than 1 hour of current time.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
Timestamp currTimeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

[image: Below are the difference in the timings]